# Lambda Expressions in T4 Templates

Tags: c#, templates, lambda, t4

Whilst putting together a T4 template I threw in a simple lambda expression:

```
<#=string.Join(",", updateFields.ConvertAll(field => field.Name).ToArray())#>
```

This causes the template to fail to generate with the error:

```
Compiling transformation: Invalid expression term '>'
```

On the line with the lambda expression.

This has been checked outside of a template and works fine. Does T4 not support working with lambda expressions? If not, are there any other language features that are unsupported in the context of a T4 template?

Thanks!

Comment: Googled http://geekswithblogs.net/gavin/archive/2010/03/13/138501.aspx, still a hack though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using T4 in Visual Studio 2008, make sure that you have C# compiler version set to 3.5 in the [template directive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160727145839/http://www.olegsych.com:80/2008/02/t4-template-directive/). It uses 2.0 by default.

Comment: Thanks, that was precisely the issue.

Comment: What if you are using T4 in Visual Studio 2012, where you get a message that says "C# 2.0 and 3.5 are no longer supported. Version 4 will always be used" after trying that ? My tt still has no support.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, you might put that code into an external class library, which you can then call from within the T4 template. I've had to do that a number of times. Its not ideal, but it works.